# How to remove zero percent slices in vertexal pie charts by R package igraph?

Tags: r, pie-chart, igraph

On each vertex there is a 2-D vector which indicates the fraction of membership of that node, and I used R package igraph to generate pie charts as vertices.

Now the problem is that: many vertices are "pure", in the sense that it only shows membership towards one group, being [0, 1] or [1, 0]. But igraph insists on plotting a degenerated line corresponding to that group, as the following screenshot suggests:

[image]

I tried to change the border by "lty=0", but that removes the circular border around each node, which is even worse.

Comment: Your question would go a long way with a reproducible example.

Comment: I guess you'll need to set the vertex shape of these vertices to `circle`.

Comment: @GaborCsardi are your saying that I should handle these two types of nodes separately? That should make sense.

Comment: @yuanz07: yes, just set `V(g)$shape` to `circle` for these vertices.